# How to equate a variable and a property inside ngIf condition in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I am issuing *ngIf inside an *ngFor loop to compare some variable to a property (uid), as shown likes this:

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let idea of ideas$|async;" >
      <ion-item-options *ngIf="idea.creatorRef.id == uid">
        {{...}}
      </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

The *ngIf condition always returns false. However, if I compare the variable or the property to a string, it works as expected. Can someone explain what is going on? If that is not allowed with Angular, how can I achieve similar functionality? Thank you.

Sample values for `idea`

```
{
  title: 'mars',
  creatorRef: {id: "aMCFCUQppCQ1WZF5AaMpFYEYYqY2", displayName: "nas"}
}
```

and `uid = "aMCFCUQppCQ1WZF5AaMpFYEYYqY2"`

Note: the functionality I want is to hide the option item whenever the ids do not match.

Comment: You can omit `this.` just like you did when you wrote `let idea of ideas$`

Comment: The use of _this._ is Ok, even considering the suggestion, the problem is the same.

Comment: can you provide an example values of both "ideas" and "uid" variables?

Comment: Thank you for your update, can you make a simple example on stackblitz.com as there is still something missing.

Comment: maybe the `uid`  does not have any values at the time of the loop runs.try to hard code the value to the uid and check.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your life with the addition of a function that handles this on the component controller, and you will save time if you have other conditions in the future and the code will be clean..

- **inside xxx.component.ts**

```
public identifiantsAreEqual(idea:TypeOfIdea) : boolean {
   // with '==' you compare just value , if you also want compare value & type 
   // make '==='
    
  return this.uid == idea.creatorRef.id;
}
```

- **change in your xxx.component.html**

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let idea of ideas$|async; >
      <ion-item-options *ngIf="identifiantsAreEqual(idea)">
        {{...}}
      </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

Comment: Binding to functions in your template can have relevance in performance, espescially in larger arrays, as they are called on every tick.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution, yet it does not work either. I think the issue is I am not able to pass the `idea` variable correctly like that, considering the context.

Comment: @MikeS.  ok we assume that we have a large list, normally we will have a pagination ... , we process your use case you can just use **trackmy**

Answer (score 0):

You write this.uid in if condition you should remove **this.** only use **uid** which you declare in **.ts** file

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let idea of ideas$|async; >
  <ion-item-options *ngIf="idea.creatorRef.id == uid">
    {{...}}
  </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

Thanks..

Comment: I don't that is an issue, but i have updated my question just to focus on the bigger problem. Tnx